# Lower portion of layout not shows when soft keyboard dissappear after edit text box

Tags: android, android-edittext, scrollview

I am using the below code fro xml file in android project.
Ther is one EditText the layout has used scrollview. When i click on EditText and write some thing and press back then softkeyboard dissappear but the lower part of the screen does not show untill i press on the screen again.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="#e9eaee"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
    >

<RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout09"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp">
    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout11"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:background="#ff4433">
    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/RelativeLayout11"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="#595B5C"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="#595B5C"/>

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView16"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/RelativeLayout11"
            android:layout_marginTop="410dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView7"
            android:text="..."/>

    <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout14"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/RelativeLayout07"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/layout_style_white_color_with_dark_bg">

        <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout10"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

            <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/ImageView06"
                    android:layout_width="60dp"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/profile_icon_gray_color"/>

            <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editText1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/ImageView06"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ImageView06"
                    android:background="#ffffff"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:hint="Write and share what you have in Mind "
                    android:textSize="15dp"
                    android:typeface="serif">


            </EditText>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout15"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/RelativeLayout10"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/RelativeLayout10"
                android:layout_below="@+id/TextView20"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:background="@drawable/layout_style_white_bg">
        </RelativeLayout>

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TextView20"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/RelativeLayout10"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/RelativeLayout10"
                android:layout_below="@+id/RelativeLayout10"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="#595B5C"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#969696"
                android:visibility="invisible"/>

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TextView21"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/RelativeLayout15"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/RelativeLayout15"
                android:layout_below="@+id/RelativeLayout15"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="#595B5C"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#969696"
                android:visibility="invisible"/>

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TextView18"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/TextView21"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/TextView21"
                android:layout_below="@+id/TextView21"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="#595B5C"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#969696"
                android:visibility="invisible"/>

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TextView11"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/TextView18"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/TextView18"
                android:layout_below="@+id/TextView18"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="#595B5C"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#969696"
                android:visibility="invisible"/>

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TextView10"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/RelativeLayout13"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/RelativeLayout13"
                android:layout_below="@+id/RelativeLayout13"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="#595B5C"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#969696"
                android:visibility="invisible"/>

        <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout13"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/RelativeLayout10"
                android:background="@drawable/layout_style_white_color_with_dark_bg">

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/TextView17"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="25dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/layout_style_dark_bg"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:onClick="Load_More_Pictures"
                    android:text="     Publish     "
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="12dp"
                    android:typeface="sans"/>

            <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/ImageView01"
                    android:layout_width="35dp"
                    android:layout_height="35dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/TextView17"
                    android:src="@drawable/camera_icon_gray_color"/>

            <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/ImageView02"
                    android:layout_width="35dp"
                    android:layout_height="35dp"
                    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/ImageView01"
                    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/ImageView01"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/ImageView01"
                    android:src="@drawable/gallery_icon_gray_color"/>

            <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/ImageView03"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/ImageView02"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="-4dp"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/ImageView02"
                    android:src="@drawable/video_icon_gray_color"/>

        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView23"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/RelativeLayout19"
            android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="..."
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="#ff3322"
            android:textSize="32dp"/>

    <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout19"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="400dp"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/RelativeLayout14"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/RelativeLayout14"
            android:layout_below="@+id/RelativeLayout14"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="#ffffff">

        <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout20"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/TextView26"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:background="@drawable/layout_style_white_bg">
        </RelativeLayout>

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TextView26"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="#595B5C"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#969696"
                android:visibility="invisible"/>

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TextView27"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/RelativeLayout20"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/RelativeLayout20"
                android:layout_below="@+id/RelativeLayout20"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="#595B5C"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#969696"
                android:visibility="invisible"/>

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TextView24"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/TextView27"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/TextView27"
                android:layout_below="@+id/TextView27"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="#595B5C"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#969696"
                android:visibility="invisible"/>

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TextView13"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/TextView24"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/TextView24"
                android:layout_below="@+id/TextView24"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="#595B5C"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#969696"
                android:visibility="invisible"/>

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TextView12"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/TextView13"
                android:layout_below="@+id/TextView13"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="#595B5C"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#969696"
                android:visibility="invisible"/>

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TextView16"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/TextView12"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/TextView12"
                android:layout_below="@+id/TextView12"
                android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="..."
                android:textColor="#000000"/>

        <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout17"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:background="@drawable/layout_style_white_color_with_dark_bg">

            <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/ImageView16"
                    android:layout_width="43dp"
                    android:layout_height="43dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/setting_icon"/>

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/TextView14"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ImageView16"
                    android:text="My Wall &amp; Feeds"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textStyle="bold"/>

            <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/ImageView15"
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/list_icon"/>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout18"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:background="@drawable/layout_style_white_bg">

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/TextView22"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="25dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/layout_style_white_color_with_dark_bg"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:onClick="Load_More_Pictures"
                    android:text="   View More   "
                    android:textColor="#e85e75"
                    android:textSize="12dp"
                    android:typeface="sans"/>

            <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/TextView22"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/TextView19"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="Loading Feeds"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:typeface="sans"/>

                <ProgressBar
                        android:id="@+id/ProgressBar01"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout07"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"

            android:background="#ff3322">

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Internet connection problem"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:typeface="sans"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When I was faced with such a problem, I changed from the RelativeLayout to the linear layout and played around with the layout weights.

This is what the design view in IntelliJ IDEA shows:
[image: this is what the design view in IntelliJ IDEA shows]

Comment: I change to linearlayout but same problme, Actually the problme airse here, when i click on edittext and enter value and then click back press then lower portion of the screen hide,although soft keyboard dissapear but white layout appears hide lower portion of my screen xml

Comment: can you please post the xml with the linear layout and i start helping from there..